# in ms azure database how do you search for a string containing _

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have this situation on my azure database where I need to search for any rows that contains the _ character. This is a special character on the database so I try to escape it but I get every row as a result.

```
select * from table where fieldColumn like '%_%'
will return everything on the table
select * from table where fieldColumn like '%\_%'
returns nothing
select * from table where fieldColumn = '_'
```

works

so how can i get that row that has only one _ and all the other ones that may have the _ on the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set whatever escape character you want, like this:

```
select * from table where fieldColumn like '%!_%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Here I am using the ! as an escape character to tell SQL Server to treat the following character, the _ , as a string literal.

See the documentation for more info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where fieldColumn like '%_%' escape '\';

[`LIKE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx):

> `escape_character`
>   Is a character that is put in front of a wildcard character to indicate that the wildcard should be interpreted as a regular character and not as a wildcard. `escape_character` is a character expression that **has no default** and must evaluate to only one character.